# Region ("selection") background color doesn't show

Tags: faces, region

Like most Emacs users I have a setup!

But there's one thing I try **not** to set : faces etc.
For one thing I'm not that good with color intuitions.
Another: all previous experiences of doing this show it breaks in some corner cases.

But now I find that the `region` face is so non-different from the rest (default) that it effectively (visually) does not exist. (Region behavior ok just color change absent)

Note that with `-r` (`--reverse-video`) a dark blue -- not optimal but at least visible -- appears.

But with plain default startup it's utterly invisible.

Other than explicitly setting the `region` face, is there some option to make the region visible? [And is this some kind of regression? I've never had this before]

---

Emacs started with `-Q` version 27.1, on ubuntu

---

Added in response to Nickd.

Default color

```
Foreground: black
DistantForeground: unspecified
Background: white
```

Region color

```
Foreground: unspecified
DistantForeground: gtk_selection_fg_color
Background: gtk_selection_bg_color
```

Searching around there does seem to be some bug:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2017-09/msg01098.html

And, reading between the lines, it seems the response is:

> Bug : yes
> Response: Wont fix

Oh Well

Comment: What does `M-x describe-face RET default RET` say? Ditto for `region`? Please add these values to your question. Also, is this Emacs in the terminal or in a GUI? Not sure whether Ubuntu does Emacs customizations the way that Debian apparently does, but  if so, you might try to disable their customizations (somehow - I'm not an Ubuntu user so I can't help you there)  and see if that's the underlying cause of the problem. Also, is `transient-mark-mode` enabled?

Comment: What's the complete, step-by-step recipe to repro the problem? Are you saying that *just `emacs -Q`* (no init file) gives you a region face that has the same background as the frame, by default, so that the region seems invisible?

Comment: @NickD Added details

Comment: @Drew Changed from -q to -Q. Same behavior

Comment: Maybe @phils will come along and explain what is going on, but the `region` setting seems funny.

Comment: The thread you link to seems to suggest that the bug was fixed by reverting a change. I don't see this problem on a newer version of Emacs on Ubuntu. If you can, perhaps installing 27.2 will solve this problem

Comment: @Tyler As best as I can see the bug report was (a) my problem (bg_color failing to bite) (b) A mesg in * Messages * to that effect. Since the "correction" seems to be a revert I assume an actual bug fix was not applied; just a silencing of mesg. ie (b) gone (a) remains (I've not actually seen the commit so would accept a correction). Also note this report is on 27.0. Mine: 27.1

Comment: Ok. I can't reproduce the problem, which suggests that it depends on your version of Emacs, or something particular about your OS. That's tricky to debug remotely. For me, the region face has the same specs as yours, and the resulting region is clearly visible and distinct from the rest of the buffer

Comment: @Tyler (If you want to dig in) Its probably related to gtk-emacs version (mis)match `GTK+ Version 3.24.23, cairo version 1.16.0` along with `emacs 27.1` is what emacs gives in `report-emacs-bug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `customize-face` -> `region` it talks about `gtk_selection_bg_color`. Indeed I get a better visible selection by selecting another theme in what the `xfce4-setttings-manager` calls `Appearance`.

Yet the nearly invisible selection background is no problem in other applications, so they probably ignore or override the theme in one of the gazillion ways this is possible in gtk.

I can put a

```css
*:selected {
  background: red;
}
```

into `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and a freshly started thunderbird uses red as the background when selecting text in an email. And `emacs` now uses red too.

While I agree with the OP that changing such colors gets one easily into a mess, in this case it is probably saner to just fix the region background color manually with `customize-face` rather than messing with the css. Except using another `Appearance` theme is an option.

(This is with emacs 29 on Ubuntu 20.04 using xfce4.)